# SQL result count changes when joining same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a complex query where I'm left joining multiple tables.  The resulting row count is 1,579,633.  However, when I add a left join for an existing table (i.e. left joining the same table twice), the resulting row count changes to 1,583,755.  I'm thinking there are duplicates and have tried to filter them with various clauses without any luck.  Here is the query:

```
select count(*) from t1 left join
(select t2a, t2b from t2 where t2c = 'FOO'
group by t2a, t2b) r on t1.t1a = r.t2b left join
(select t2a, t2b from t2 where t2d = 'BAR'
group by t2a, t2b) r2 on r.t2a = r2.t2a
where t1.ID in (...)
```

Note that, if possible, I'd combine the `t2` joins into a single join, but the rows in `t2` matching `'FOO'` and `'BAR'` are different.  So I'm selecting a subset of `t2a` values from `t2` and then using this subset to match other rows with the same `t2a` values and `t2d = 'BAR'`.  Each resulting row should be of the form:

```
t1.t1a | t1.t1b | ... | t2.t2a | t2.t2b
```

It's possible that `t2a` may be null, and if so,  `t2b` would be as well in the result set.

The second left join of `t2` is introducing additional rows in the result set that shouldn't be there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I see r but not r1, as in "r1.t2a = r2.t2a".

Comment: Sorry, typo, I've fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right in supposing that there are duplicates - more than 1 unique value for t2b for some values of t2a.  Try running the following SQL:

```
SELECT Base.t2a, COUNT(*) as t2bcnt
FROM
(
select t2a, t2b from t2 where t2d = 'BAR'
group by t2a, t2b
) AS Base
GROUP BY Base.t2a
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY Base.t2a
```

*(note that the inner lines are the query in your second left join)*

That will give you the dupes from your second query that are "exploding" the rows.

Comment: 72 rows in the result, most with t2bcnt = 2.  I noticed a '5' and a couple '3's as well.